# How to cast a child to base so that it ceases to be recognised as a child

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

Suppose

```
class A {
    public A() {}
}
class B : A {
    public B() {}
}
```

Now I want to cast from B to A, so that the casted object **is** no longer a B.

```
B b = new B();
A a = (A) b; // some kind of casting
bool res = a is B; // I want it to be false
```

Comment: Do you absolutely need to do it by casting? If not you could use automapper to map your child object to a new parent object

Comment: That's not how inheritance works.  Perhaps if you explained a bit more about why you want that, an alternative could be found.

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to achieve. Your example is exactly how the type system and inheritance works. Without more context it is not possible to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: Casting does not change an object's actual type.

Comment: but: a **is** B. and always will be. by your definition.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot downcast. However you have several options to archive something similar.

1) Make a constructor for A that takes B as a parameter and create a new A using whatever properties you need from B. (EDIT: As Kevin Krumwiede said, this is a bad idea and should not be done)

2) Use automapper to map B to A.

```
B b = new B();
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<B, A>();     
A a = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<A>(b);
```

These are the first ones at the top of my head, there are probably more options.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @AlPrihodko - does that answer resolve your issue? It is not clear from your question.

Comment: A constructor is a bad idea. Superclasses should not reference subclasses.

Comment: @ironstone13 I'm waiting if any other way is proposed.